# Nested Fragments - communication between child fragments in a parent fragment in a viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager, android-support-library

I'm working on the initial design of an app here and I've run into some issues with how I'd like things to work.

Some background to start:

The app is using ActionBarSherlock for the overall UI.  It's a tabbed design which uses a ViewPager along with a FragmentStatePagerAdapter to swap between the different tabs(which are SherlockFragments).

One tab in particular is a master-detail style SherlockFragment which contains and displays two nested fragments, a SherlockListFragment(the master) and a regular SherlockFragment(the detail).

All the examples I've seen on how to create a master/detail with fragments show the list communicating with the detail via an interface callback which is then implemented in the FragmentActivity that the master/detail fragments are attached to.

In my case though there is no FragmentActivity, the two Fragments are inside a parent SherlockFragment.  How can I get the listFragments onItemSelected to update the detailFragment? Is it possible to set up an interface callback between two Fragments directly(or through the parent Fragment) without involving a FragmentActivity?